# How to make this move longer without pauses

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this code which work perfectly if I want to move one block, but when I will keep the key pressed, animation will work but with those pauses. I figured out that multiply speed and distance will work, but I have no idea how to add this "live" to animation. Can you give me some advice?

```js
var Xpos = 0;
var Ypos = 0;
var spd = 250;
var dstnc = 100;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 87) {
    $('#movThs').animate({
      top: -dstnc + Ypos + 'px'
    }, spd);
    Ypos = Ypos - dstnc;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 68) {
    $('#movThs').animate({
      left: dstnc + Xpos + 'px'
    }, spd);
    Xpos = Xpos + dstnc;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    $('#movThs').animate({
      top: dstnc + Ypos + 'px'
    }, spd);
    Ypos = Ypos + dstnc;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    $('#movThs').animate({
      left: -dstnc + Xpos + 'px'
    }, spd);
    Xpos = Xpos - dstnc;
  }
});
```

```css
#movThs {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="movThs"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact easing behaviour you wish to implement, but one handy hint to making things smoother is to `stop()` before re-animating.

It ends up with non-discrete positioning; with the stop(), you can now be left between two positions, which may not be what you want. What it does do is prevent animation-queues from building up (without sacrificing the original smoothness).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  #movThs {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 90%;
  }
</style>

<div id="movThs"></div>
<script>
  var Xpos = 0;
  var Ypos = 0;
  var spd = 250;
  var dstnc = 100;

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 87) {
      $('#movThs').stop().animate({
        top: -dstnc + Ypos + 'px'
      }, spd);
      Ypos = Ypos - dstnc;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 68) {
      $('#movThs').stop().animate({
        left: dstnc + Xpos + 'px'
      }, spd);
      Xpos = Xpos + dstnc;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 83) {
      $('#movThs').stop().animate({
        top: dstnc + Ypos + 'px'
      }, spd);
      Ypos = Ypos + dstnc;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 65) {
      $('#movThs').stop().animate({
        left: -dstnc + Xpos + 'px'
      }, spd);
      Xpos = Xpos - dstnc;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `spd` is really the time it takes for an operation to complete

The variable `dstnc` is the distance to travel in said time for the operation

My Answer is below, has `spd` which really is time to do operation to 10 milliseconds

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  #movThs {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 90%;
  }
</style>

<div id="movThs"></div>
<script>
  var Xpos = 0;
  var Ypos = 0;
  var spd = 10; //the amount of time it takes (milliseconds)
  var dstnc = 100; //the distance to travel (pixels)

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 87) {
      $('#movThs').animate({
        top: -dstnc + Ypos + 'px'
      }, spd);
      Ypos = Ypos - dstnc;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 68) {
      $('#movThs').animate({
        left: dstnc + Xpos + 'px'
      }, spd);
      Xpos = Xpos + dstnc;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 83) {
      $('#movThs').animate({
        top: dstnc + Ypos + 'px'
      }, spd);
      Ypos = Ypos + dstnc;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 65) {
      $('#movThs').animate({
        left: -dstnc + Xpos + 'px'
      }, spd);
      Xpos = Xpos - dstnc;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider not using JQuery but pure JS, I would suggest giving a try to below snippet.

Regards

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
if (document.animationInitialized) {
    return;
}

document.animationInitialized = true;

const movThs = document.getElementById("movThs");
const UP = "W".charCodeAt(0);
const DOWN = "S".charCodeAt(0);
const RIGHT = "D".charCodeAt(0);
const LEFT = "A".charCodeAt(0);
const XMAX = 50;
const YMAX = 50;

let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let ax = 0;
let ay = 0;
let cx = 0;
let cy = 0;

function clamp(v, min, max) {
    return v < min ? min : v > max ? max : v;
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(function onAnimation() {
    if (!x) {
        if (ax) {
            ax += -Math.sign(ax);
        }
    } else {
        ax += x;
        ax = clamp(ax, -XMAX, XMAX);
    }
    cx += ax / 100;

    if (!y) {
        if (ay) {
            ay += -Math.sign(ay);
        }
    } else {
        ay += y;
        ay = clamp(ay, -YMAX, YMAX);
    }
    cy += ay / 100;

    movThs.style.transform = `translate3d(${cx}rem,${cy}rem,0)`

    window.requestAnimationFrame(onAnimation);
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    switch (event.which) {
        case UP:
            y = -1;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            x = -1;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            x = 1;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            y = 1;
            break;
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    switch (event.which) {
        case UP:
        case DOWN:
            y = 0;
            break;
        case LEFT:
        case RIGHT:
            x = 0;
            break;
    }
}, false);

});

if (document.readyState === "complete") {
document.dispatchEvent(new Event("DOMContentLoaded"));
}
```

```css
#movThs {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="movThs"></div>
```